# in genfromtxt next(fhd), StopIteration error upon adding a new "with open file" line

Tags: python, numpy

I've got an input file that needs to be analyzed (it's a trajectory file that contains 4 frames) and that involves a for loop for each frame and making a temporary file then the calculations. The calculations together with some info from the input file would be written to an output file. Here is my code. "solvent" and "refpts" are names of lists which contains numbers. The contents of those lists are needed in the out file.

```
with open(infile, 'rb') as fi:
    with open(outfile,'a') as fj:
        fj.write('C, O, C-O distance, q, hbond')
        fj.write('\n')
        for frame in range(fr+1):
            fj.write(str(frame))
            fj.write('\n')
            chunk = list(islice(fi, nlines))
            #writes the snapshot's coordinate in a temporary file 'frame.gro'
            with open('frame.gro', 'w') as out:
                for line in chunk:
                    out.write(line)
            with open("frame.gro", 'r') as f:
                o = np.genfromtxt("frame.gro", dtype=None, skip_header=2, usecols=(0,1,3,4,5), max_rows=atoms) #this is line 182
                # obtain info, then do calcs ...
            for n in range(len(solvent)):
                for i in range(len(refpts)):
                    #calcs, add items to lists, etc
                    fj.write(str(refpts[i]))
            # ...rest of the code
```

Everything works fine until I added every line which included the "fj". This error occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "script.py", line 182, in 
>       o = np.genfromtxt("frame.gro", dtype=None, skip_header=2, usecols=(0,1,3,4,5), max_rows=atoms)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1707, in genfromtxt
>       next(fhd)
>   StopIteration

What could I do?

EDIT: changed a word in the title
EDIT #2: included the actual line with the error

Comment: Why do you `open` 'frame.gro', and then use the same file name in `genfromtxt`.  If you give the filename to `genfromtxt`, it opens it for its own read.  Either pass `f` to `genfromtxt`, or don't embed the `gen` in that `with` block.

Comment: If cleaning up those file `open` doesn't solve this, I'd check the size of the `frame.gro` file.  Does it really have 2 header lines?  How many data lines. What is `atoms`?

Comment: @hpaulj I need to write first then read.

Comment: I'm not asking about the write.  I' ask about the redundant read open.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment

```
        with open("frame.gro", 'r') as f:
            o = np.genfromtxt("frame.gro", dtype=None, skip_header=2, usecols=(0,1,3,4,5), max_rows=atoms) #this is line 182
            # obtain info, then do calcs ...
```

Why do you open `frame.gro`, and but not use the opened file?  The `genfromtxt` line uses the filename, not `f`.  I don't know of if that redundant opening is causing the error, but it does suggest some sloppy thinking and/or testing.

I can get StopIteration Errors if I try to apply `genfromtxt` to a file with too few lines - too few to `skip`.  The error line number is different but that may be because I'm using a different Py3 numpy.

You need to check the newly written `frame.gro` and make sure it fits your assumptions in the `genfromtxt` - size, content, etc.